# How to group anagrams together of a array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to write a function called `anagram()` and return the following output:

```
Example =  ['Creams', 'bart','bAtr', 'bar', 'rabt', 'Cars','creamsery', 'Scar', 'scream']

puts anagram(Example)
```

OUTPUT:

```
 [["Creams", "scream"] ["bart", "bAtr", "rabt"], ["bar"], ["Cars","Scar"],["creamsery"]]
```

I know I can use:

```
Example[i].downcase.char.sort.join
```

to compare each element in the array, but I have a hard time grouping them all together inside a loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We would prefer to see your code attempt, to help you fix any errors, rather than create something totally unrelated and you have to shoehorn it into place. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```ruby
def anagrams(ary)
  h = Hash.new([])
  ary.each.with_index { |el, i| h[el.downcase.chars.sort.join] += [i] }
  h.map { |key, indexes| indexes.map { |i| ary[i] } }
end
```

The function saves the indexes in a hash and then returns the corresponding elements.

This approach scans the array at most twice, therefore it's O(n). Even if it is not particularly elegant, it is quite fast.

Comment: I believe this is O(n log n) due to the fact that you're sorting every element within a loop.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony. I meant it's O(n) where n is the number of word. To be complete given the maximum number of chars per word "k". This algorithm is:
O(n * k log k). However I think that "k" should be small enough.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
def anagram(ary)
  ary.map do |el| 
    ary.select{ |x| el.downcase.chars.sort.join('') == x.downcase.chars.sort.join('') }
  end.uniq
end
```

Calling `.chars` on a `String` will provide you an `Array` of chars that you can sort and then `.join` back to a `String`.

You can try it on the console:

```
> ary = ['Creams', 'bart','bAtr', 'bar', 'rabt', 'Cars','creamsery', 'Scar', 'scream']
> anagram ary
=> [["Creams", "scream"], ["bart", "bAtr", "rabt"], ["bar"], ["Cars", "Scar"], ["creamsery"]]
```

Of course, this is not particularly elegant or efficient. I'm eager to learn from others.

Answer (score 0):

```
Example.group_by{|w| w.downcase.chars.sort}.values
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner -

```
array.inject({}){|hash, ele| key = ele.chars.sort.join.downcase; hash[key] = (hash[key] || []) + [ele]; hash }.values
```

**Complexity - O(n * mlogm)**, where **n** => number of elements, **m** => max size of string length.

If value of **m** is negligible comparing to **n** then complexity will be **O(n)**